# How to convert different data-types to bytes in c++?

Tags: c++, user-defined-data-types

I have a structure that looks like:

```
typedef struct{
  float distance;
  float reflectivity;      
}data_point;

typedef struct{
  int flag;
  float Azimuth;
  data_point points[32];
}data_block;
```

- A `data point` is represented in the packet by three bytes - two bytes of `distance` and one byte of calibrated `reflectivity`. The distance is an unsigned integer. It has 2 mm granularity. Hence, a reported value of 51,154 represents 102,308 mm or 102.308 m. Calibrated `reflectivity` is reported on a scale of 0 to 255. The elevation angle (ω) is inferred based on the position of the data point within a data block.
- `flag` from float to 2 bytes(constant 0xFFEE)
- A two-byte `azimuth` value (α) appears after the flag bytes at the beginning of each data block. The azimuth is an unsigned integer. It represents an angle in hundredths of a degree. Therefore, a raw value of 27742 should be interpreted as 277.42°

[image]

[image]

How can I create a vector of 100 bytes of binary data? ( 2 + 2 + (32x3))?

Comment: You can't assume that the classes will have no padding, as your calculation implies.

Comment: std::array<char,96> is 96 bytes.

Comment: One tedious option unaffected by compiler padding is to replace your structs with something that is exactly the size you desire (perhaps using a size setting constructor).  Consider a std::vector<T>, where T might be uint8_t or char.  Then add methods to read or write each field.  When only a 'few' fields, this is not too bad, but it can grow quickly.  A team I know used this approach when the 'other compiler' (sender vs receiver) was different, and either compiler padded differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either:

- Use a (custom) solution, as long as the compiler is instructed for not padding data
- Rely on a serialization library. You could e.g. use [SerializeToArray()](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message_lite?csw=1#MessageLite.SerializeToArray.details) provided by [Google's protobuf library](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/)

Comment: So many solutions, I would also offer [Google's Flattbuffers](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/) and [Boost Serialization](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html).

Comment: @tom Thank you for the contribution. If I'm not mistaking, flatbuffers are not by Google.

Comment: I think they were written by Wouter van Oortmerssen while working at  Fun Propulsion Labs, Google. I could be wrong though...